# Binding data to treeview nodes from array issue in react

Tags: reactjs

I have follow below example to create tree view with check boxes. Its working fine.

https://github.com/jakezatecky/react-checkbox-tree

Now I am trying to add data from my post method. I have fill data to array. But I tried to add it to loop for get data.

```
const persons = []; 
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  persons = [{ value: data[i].id, label: data[i].name }]; 
}  
this.setState({ persons });
```

Checkbox code

```
  render() {
        return (
            <CheckboxTree
                nodes={this.state.persons}
                iconsClass="fa5"
                checked={this.state.checked}
                expanded={this.state.expanded} 
                onExpand={expanded => this.setState({ expanded })}
            />
        );
    }
```

I am getting only last record in this treeview. but loop is working correctly Please give some suggestions to solve this. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the last object only because you are re-initialing the `person` array each time.

Instead you have to **push** that object to the array.

Try like this:

```
const persons = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  persons.push({ value: data[i].id, label: data[i].name }) 
}
this.setState({ persons });
```

Comment: If your issue is resolved then you can give a up-vote for my motivation :).....

Comment: @Bidhudatta  Done. Sorry for late

Comment: I have a small question regarding this. If I have children inside this one. then can we use it inside this one without loop it @Bibhudatta Sahoo

Comment: Yes if you have children record then you can add the object children at place of Value label.

Comment: you meant like this   persons.push({ value: data[i].id, label: data[i].name,
                children: [
                         { value: data[i].id, label: data[i].name}]
 })

Comment: But if we have more than one children then do we need another loop for that @bibhudatta

Comment: Yes if you have array of children then you definitely need a loop.